# Does sleep function in a service affect android boot time

Tags: android, shell, android-source

I need to write a service which has to start at android boot time from init.rc.

If i am giving a huge delay in service daemon shell script with sleep function, does this delay increases the android boot time?

The service does not depend on any other events.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that it will not influence on the boot time. init starts a new service in a new forked process, so the sleep in your service will not influence on boot time.

However, maybe it's worth to add your service after boot?

Comment: I actually need the service to start just after boot,how can we do this from init.rc?

Comment: I think you can just add your service and start it receiveing onBoot intent.